# Get current visible QListWidget items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistview

Is there a way I can get the current items displayed in the visible area of the QListWidget

I have tried this sample code but it is only returning the first item of the list.

```
def get_visible_cameras(listWidget):
    rect = listWidget.viewport().contentsRect()
    top = listWidget.indexAt(rect.topLeft())
    if top.isValid():
        bottom = listWidget.indexAt(rect.bottomLeft())
        if not bottom.isValid():
            bottom = listWidget.model().index(listWidget.count() - 1)
        for index in range(top.row(), bottom.row() + 1):
            yield listWidget.item(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any function with `yield` in its definition will return a generator. In order to get all items you would then need to iterate over this generator, i.e. do something like

```
for item in get_visible_cameras(listWidget):
    do_something_with(item)
```

If you simple want to return a list of items, you can do something like this instead:

```
def get_visible_cameras(listWidget):
    rect = listWidget.viewport().contentsRect()
    top = listWidget.indexAt(rect.topLeft())
    result = []
    if top.isValid():
        bottom = listWidget.indexAt(rect.bottomLeft())
        if not bottom.isValid():
            bottom = listWidget.model().index(listWidget.count() - 1)
        for index in range(top.row(), bottom.row() + 1):
            result.append(listWidget.item(index))
    return result
```

Comment: Hi @Heike. It is returning only the first item of the QlistWidget.

Comment: It is working for a test app I constructed. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your side  there is not much more I can suggest.